# CollectionEditor's Parent

Tags: c#, .net, collectioneditor

I have a property like that:

```
[Editor(typeof(LayerCollection), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public List<Layer> Layers { get { return layers; } }
```

And I have a `LayerCollection` class that derived from **CollectionEditor**. And this `Layers` property is in `Canvas`class. Now, the `Layer` object needs to know about `Canvas` class which is the parent of the collection. So how can I get the parent of the CollectionEditor named `LayerCollection`?

Or if it is impossible, can I pass a parameter to the **CollectionEditor** when it is created? By this way I can pass the `Canvas` object as a parameter to the `Layer` when it is created.

Comment: The first argument to EditValue() is an ITypeDescriptorContext that gives you the context you need.  Its Instance property references the control.

Comment: Hans, thanks but when I get the parent like that: `this.parent = (Canvas)context.Instance;`, it gives me **null**.

Comment: Actually, I got the problem. it gives me **null** because of `TypeConverter` class. Thanks again, `EditValue()` does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hans Passant" answered my question in the first post's comment:

> The first argument to EditValue() is an ITypeDescriptorContext that gives you the context you need. Its Instance property references the control. – Hans Passant